# Writing a SQL Update statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know how to write a SQL statement for the following senario;

I have a table, which consist of 2 columns. `ParentName` and `No_Of_Kids`. so say we have a record called parent `A` and parent `A` had 2 kids.(in 2008)

Now in 2011 Parent `A` has got another 3 kids, so i need to update this table, to say Parent `A` has 5 kids altogether.

```
UPDATE ParentKidsTable
SET parentName=value, No_Of_kids=??? // (how to write the SQL no. of Kids in 2008 + no. of kids in 2011)
WHERE parentName=some_value
```

Comment: Why are you setting parentName again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're looking for the generic case of adding N kids, so you don't have to look up the value No_Of_Kids first in which case you can do:

```
UPDATE ParentKidsTable
SET No_Of_Kids = No_Of_Kids + 3
WHERE ParentName = 'some_value'
```

Answer (score 2):

The general statement to update a table is:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = 'newValue'
WHERE otherfield = 'condition'
```

So in your case this makes:

```
UPDATE ParentKidsTable
SET No_Of_Kids = 5
WHERE ParentName = 'some_value'
```

This would update the `No_Of_Kids` to 5 where the `ParentName` equals `some_value`. Make sure you put the String literals between apostrophes.

If you want to add a certain number of kids to the yet existing number you can do:

```
UPDATE ParentKidsTable
SET No_Of_Kids = (No_Of_Kids + 3)
WHERE ParentName = 'some_value'
```

which is basically short (and better) for:

```
UPDATE ParentKidsTable
SET No_Of_Kids = ((SELECT No_Of_Kids 
                  FROM ParentKidsTable 
                  WHERE ParentName = 'some_value') + 3)
WHERE ParentName = 'some_value'
```

Comment: Or `SET No_Of_Kids = No_Of_Kids + 3`

Comment: No, i only know the number of kids in 2011 (which is 3), so i have to add the previous 2 kids with the new kids (3), and update it as 5. how can i do this ?

Comment: Actually i want to add a Value to a previously saved value. 2+3=5

Answer (score 2):

To increment number of kids:

```
UPDATE ParentKidsTable
SET No_Of_Kids = No_Of_Kids + 3
WHERE ParentName = 'some_value'
```